React Theme Switching Not Updating Components
I'm encountering an issue with theme switching in my React application. The application supports two themes, which I'll refer to as Theme One and Theme Two. I've implemented lazy loading to dynamically load the corresponding theme components based on the selected theme.
Each theme defines its own styling for a common button class. For example, in Theme One, the button has a blue color, while in Theme Two, it has a brown color.
The problem arises when I switch themes using a button. Initially, when transitioning from Theme One to Theme Two, the button color updates correctly from brown to blue. However, after switching back to Theme One, the button color fails to revert to brown as expected. Subsequent theme switches also don't reflect any changes in the button color.
code: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/wizardly-robinson-v774zf?file=%2Fsrc%2FDashboard.tsx%3A12%2C14
// App.js
import React, { createContext, useState, startTransition, useEffect } from "react";
// Lazy load themes
const ThemeOne = React.lazy(() => import("./themes/theme-one"));
const ThemeTwo = React.lazy(() => import("./themes/theme-two"));

export const MawbThemeContext = createContext({ _theme: "" });

const App = () => {
  const [_theme, setTheme] = useState("themeOne");

  const handleChangeTheme = () => {
    startTransition(() => {
      if (_theme === "themeOne") {
        setTheme("themeTwo");
      } else {
        setTheme("themeOne");
      }
    });
  };

  let themeComponent;
  if (_theme === "themeOne") {
    themeComponent = <ThemeOne handleChangeTheme={handleChangeTheme} />;
  } else if (_theme === "themeTwo") {
    themeComponent = <ThemeTwo handleChangeTheme={handleChangeTheme} />;
  } else {
    themeComponent = <ThemeTwo handleChangeTheme={handleChangeTheme} />;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    startTransition(() => {
      console.log("transition", _theme); // Ensure theme is changing correctly
    });
  }, [_theme]);

  return (
    <>
      <MawbThemeContext.Provider value={{ _theme }}>
        {themeComponent}
      </MawbThemeContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;


I would appreciate any insights into why the theme updates are not being reflected correctly, especially when transitioning between themes multiple times.

The issue comes from the css import lines in your components
import "../scss/index.theme.one.scss";
import "../scss/index.theme.two.scss";

If you check the rendered HTML in your application you can see the following behavior.
The first time your app launch, only the ThemeOne component was called, so if you inspect the css you'll see only the first one was loaded :

However, as soon as you switch theme the second import line is called, that mean the second css file is called :

At this moment, you can switch as much as you want, the second css file is taking the lead on the first one, this is why you can't get your brown button anymore.
To fix this you will have to deal with the context passed through your component.
For example use hooks to get current context and apply the correct css properties. An example here

Hello! I attempted to integrate the context feature, but it appears that the CSS file included in the header section doesn't update when switching themes.
